# How to make the size of the font according to the size frame?

Tags: html

I have a problem on the portal inside the website, I suspect my website built with Python is not able to reduce the size and fit in the frame, so now I wish to try to make the website have responsive structure, but I don't want the website to change the position, so any idea on how to have responsive structure without changing the position and the arrangement of the website?

Comment: What did you already try? please provide some code.

Comment: i have try to remove some code for example col-6 or col-9 but i still fail to fix the website in another website by using <iframe>

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: iframe cannot be made responsive with only CSS.. you must use javascript/jquery to manually resize the iframe width and height when required.

Comment: which part of code?

Comment: The code that is related to this question

Comment: if you want to resize iframe with css, you should make it manually by media query with multiple values of width and height to appropriate with screen size